# How do I send and receive an integer array from client to server in Java socket programming?

Tags: sockets, client-server

I'm having a problem sending a job (an integer array) from client to server in two different packages over a socket connection. Any ideas please?

I can explain further if my question is not clear enough.

Comment: What problem? And what do you mean by "packages"?

Comment: Please post an example of the offending code.  It will help tremendously in giving you guidance.

Comment: What do you mean by needing two different packages? Do you mean packets? If so, you should need to worry about the number or size of the packets.

Answer (score 4):

To answer the question in your title, I would wrap the `SocketOutputStream` in a `BufferedOutputStream` in a `DataOutputStream` and use the latter's `writeInt()` method repeatedly. Or you could use `ObjectOutputStream` in place of `DataOutputStream`, and serialize the array: `objOutStream.writeObject(theArray)`. To read it in again on the other end, just wrap the `SocketInputStream` in (1) a `DataInputStream` and use `readInt()` repeatedly, or (2) a `ObjectInputStream` and use `readObject()`.

(If you don't have to interoperate with other languages, `Object*Stream` is easier on you)

Comment: Sorry could you be more technical by translating the answer you send into code or pseudocode please?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have to send it as an array? It complicates the whole process. Why not wrap it in a Collection or some sort of List? I.e:

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(...);
oos.writeObject(integerCollection);



ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(...);
Collection integerCollection = (Collection)ois.readObject();
```

Answer (score 0):

What protocol are you using to send this data over your link? 
You can wrap your array in an object that can be serialized into an output stream.

***TCP:*** Things should be pretty simple in this case. The transport layer will take care of fragmenting your object and getting it right at the other end of the link.

***UDP:*** Things can get a little bit complicated; If the object you are trying to serialize is bigger than the UDP buffers (in terms of bytes) then you might not be able to get the data through. In this situation, you can send your data in chunks that are smaller than the default UDP buffer size.

Regards,

Answer (score -3):

using

```
ArrayList a=new ArrayList(n)    //n represents size
```

or

```
List a=new List()
```

we can send to a server